# Creating polygon and adding it as new layer with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon-creation

I'm attempting to add a polygon to a new layer using PyQGIS in QGIS 3.14.  Adapting some examples from questions and answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86812/how-to-draw-polygons-from-the-python-console) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141371/how-to-implement-add-feature-action-from-pyqgis). I believe I have successfully created the polygon from an array of (four) input points and then a feature that contains the polygon.

I have then created a layer for the feature in the CRS I desire but cannot work how to get the feature into the layer. Code so far below.

```py
# Attach modules 
from qgis.core import *                        # attach main QGIS library
from qgis.utils import *                       # attach main python library
import os                                      # attach operating system library

# Create an array [] object with the polygon vertices
vrtcs = []
vrtcs.append(QgsPointXY(396100,8969000))
vrtcs.append(QgsPointXY(396100,8973900))
vrtcs.append(QgsPointXY(397900,8973900))
vrtcs.append(QgsPointXY(397900,8969000))

# Create a polygon from the coordinates
ply_01 = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([vrtcs])

# Create a feature object then put the polygon into the feature
ftr = QgsFeature()
ftr.setGeometry(ply_01)
print(ftr.geometry())

# Create a layer for the feature, in the desired CRS
lyr = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:29194', '200905_Bdy',"org")
Prj.addMapLayers([lyr]) 

# Set an object for the data provider for the layer
prv = lyr.dataProvider()                               

# Add the feature to the layer using this provider (fails)
prv.addFeatures([ftr])
```

Answer (score 5):

Change `'org'` into `'memory'` and add `Prj = QgsProject.instance()` line before using `Prj`.

```
...

# Create a layer for the feature, in the desired CRS
lyr = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:29194', '200905_Bdy', "memory")
Prj = QgsProject.instance()  # ADD THIS LINE
Prj.addMapLayers([lyr])
```

Since you add one layer, you can use `Prj.addMapLayer(lyr)` instead of `Prj.addMapLayers([lyr])`.

```
...
```

Comment: Kadir - thanks for the reply. I did set a reference Prj = QgsProject.instance()  higher up in the script but forgot to include it in the post.  However this did not work as I still get the error TypeError: QgsProject.addMapLayers(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer' when I run the line Prj.addMapLayers(lyr)

Comment: You should use `addMapLayer`, not `addMapLayers`. `...Layers([lyr])` -> `...Layer(lyr)`

Comment: Thanks, Kadir that works no to get it to display!

Comment: I found using prv.addFeatures([ftr]) more meaningful as the console reports on execuation 'True, [<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x000002116B69A288>])', while using prv.addFeatures(ftr) there console reports is '(True, [])' , the latter being a bit crytpic for the novice scripter

Answer (score 3):

You must [start editing](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/core/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=layer%20commitchanges#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.startEditing) before adding the feature to the layer and [commit the changes](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/core/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=layer%20commitchanges#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.commitChanges) after you are done:

```
if feature.isValid():
    layer.startEditing()
    layer.addFeatures([feature])
    commited = layer.commitChanges()
    if commited:
        return True
    else:
        print(f'{layer.commitErrors()}')
        return False
```